# How can I get find to match a pattern a specific number of times?

Tags: regex, linux, command-line, find, pattern-matching

I have a bunch of files with extensions that are numbers with varying numbers of digits. I want to find to show me everything with three digits, but can't figure out a nice way of doing this. The following works, but seems clunky:

```
find . -name "*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

It seems like there should be some way to specify the number of times the pattern has to show up. What if I wanted to catch everything with three or four digits, but not two or five? Should I put this ridiculous pattern in with a -o switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `-name` switch for this. You need to use `find -regex`

```
find . -regex "^.*\.[0-9]\{3,4\}$"
```

This will find all file names with with 3 or 4 digits in extension.

Comment: That worked. I tried something like this earlier, but accidentally escaped the asterisk rather than the period. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out. (Not sure why someone downvoted it without any comment).

Comment: I'm not sure either. I notice the other answer also seems to have been downvoted without comment (although it wasn't really correct, so that may have been why it got downvoted).

Comment: It is annoying when people down-vote a working solution without leaving comment on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Put the repetition amount in curly braces:

```
[0-9]{3}
```

Comment: Thanks, but posix style pattern matching doesn't seem to work with find.